# Is there a way to find all questions that refer to some other question?

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks, reference

Is there a way to find all questions that refer via a link to some other question in SO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts/47808#47808

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To demonstrate, I will link to another question.

[Show posts that link to your questions on recent activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52390/show-posts-that-link-to-your-questions-on-recent-activity)

Notice that the right-hand side of this page now has a **Linked** section, referring to the question I just linked.

Comment: Of note, this works both ways.  Not only does it include questions that this question (and its answers) link to, but also other questions that link to *it*

Answer (score 1):

Look at the **`Linked`** section in the right-hand side of the question's page.

It shows both the questions linked **from** this question,
and the questions having a link **to** this question.

> [image: screenshot of the section]